# ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /

Tags: django, pki, ca

We currently have a CA setup with django connected through its API (dogtag). We recently set up a new subordinate CA and tried to redirect django to this new IP, however we are receiving the following error when submitting a CSR request to my CA using django:

```
KeyError at /
'Output'

Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://10.10.50.4/
Django Version: 2.2.14
Python Executable: /app/PKIWeb/venv/bin/python3.6 Python Version: 3.6.6 Python Path: ['/app/PKIWeb', '/app/PKIWeb/venv/bin', '/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib64/python36.zip', '/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib64/python3.6', '/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time: Sáb, 26 Jun 2021 21:14:30 -0400 Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core',
 'api',
 'django_extensions',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_api_key',
 'drf_yasg']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'camaracomercio.middleware.CsrAPILocaleMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/app/PKIWeb/core/views.py" in form_valid
  39.             cert_request_infos = self.request_ca_certificate(data, profile)

File "/app/PKIWeb/core/views.py" in request_ca_certificate
  62.         enroll_request = client.create_enrollment_request(profile, data)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pki/__init__.py" in handler
  304.                 return fn_call(inst, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pki/cert.py" in create_enrollment_request
  962.         enrollment_template = self.get_enrollment_template(profile_id)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pki/__init__.py" in handler
  304.                 return fn_call(inst, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pki/cert.py" in get_enrollment_template
  945.         enrollment_template = CertEnrollmentRequest.from_json(r.json())

File "/app/PKIWeb/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pki/cert.py" in from_json
  520.         outputs = attr_list['Output']

Exception Type: KeyError at /
Exception Value: 'Output'
```

This only happens with my new CA, this means I had an old CA setup and didn't face these issues.

Any inputs?

Comment: I've the same problem, and I'm here for this reason... Now I'm sad